# What are the syntax specifications (keyword/context keyword ordering) for c++ function signatures?

Tags: c++

The riches of c++ expressiveness and syntax, make it somewhat difficult to use multiple features of the language on a single signature.

For example I'd like to declare a **member function**<sup>[1]</sup> as being :

- `virtual`
- `override` // example of a context keyword
- `noexcept`
- `const`
- having a trailing return type

It gets more complicated if we consider that functions can also be

- defaulted
- deleted
- final (for virtual methods)
- templates
- explicit specializations
- `[[deprecated]]`
- ... and many many more I can't know/suspect right now

The standard's wording looks Greek to me and even that was not true, I can't know what works with what (or what's a syntactic mishap, eg <sup>[1]</sup> might even be illegal).

I know that reading individual features (override, noexcept etc) will help, but **is there a guide on how to use them in coaction ?** (**syntactically** speaking; I **don't** expect/want an answer on the functionallity of the features)

### EDIT

Just in case it helps, I think the excerpt to be deciphered is the following

> 8.4.1 Function deﬁnitions have the form
>
> **function-deﬁnition**: attribute-speciﬁer-seqopt decl-speciﬁer-seqopt declarator virt-speciﬁer-seqopt function-body

Comment: Essentially, you want to know, which of these specifications can go together with which others and which combinations are impossible?

Comment: @Walter Yes, and where the order matters or the syntax has multiple valid orders

Comment: Why is this being closed as "unclear what you're asking"? It is crystal clear what OP is asking.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Clear after the second reading, but by no means *crystal clear*.

Comment: @Walter why, what don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a copy of the spec, you can look for the grammar in each section.  It sounds like you want a *complete* guide to what is and is not correct, and the spec is the only real source for this information.  Fortunately, it's not that difficult to read, it's just time-consuming and tedious.

Here is the grammar for function definitions, taken from the beginning of section 8.4.1 of N3690.  I suggest reading a primer on context-free grammars first ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) - skip to the examples).  Note that everybody has their own variation on how they write context-free grammars, so the grammar in the C++ spec will be a little different from what you see in, say, Wikipedia or a compilers textbook.

```
function-definition:
    attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt declarator virt-specifier-seqopt function-body
function-body:
    ctor-initializeropt compound-statement
    function-try-block
    = default ;
    = delete ;
```

Reading this, we see that "function-body" has four alternatives, one on each line.  Two alternatives `= delete` and `= default`, so those go in the same place that a `{ ... }` more interesting function body would go.  (The *function try block* is a bit of an obscure way of defining a function in C++, so let's just ignore it.)

For "function-definition", you can see it has one line, so there is only one way to define a function.  Each item in the line has to appear in order.  Parts with the "opt" subscript are optional.  So,

1. Attributes first
2. Declaration specifiers next (e.g., `static`, `int`, `extern`...)
3. Declarators after that (e.g. `function_name(int x, int y) -> int`)
4. Virtual specifier after that (`override` or `final`)
5. Function body last (this includes normal function bodies `{ ... }` as well as `= delete` and `= default`)

Once you have a little practice reading CFGs, it becomes second nature.  The only hard part is jumping around the C++ spec to find all of the definitions you want.

### Notes

Also note that the grammar will only tell you the syntax.  If you *just* read the grammar, you'll write nonsense like:

```
// permissible, according to the grammar
extern static const void long short int int x;
```

Reading the text will explain that you can't, e.g., have a `short long`, even though it's permitted by the grammar.

The other trick is finding the definition you're looking for.  As Serthy asks below, how do you specify pure functions?  Where does `= 0` go?  Well, you can find that `= 0` appears in section 9.2 as `pure-specifier`, but it can only appear on a `member-declarator`.  So it can't appear in `function-definition`, it can only appear in a "declaration".  The declaration and definition syntax is slightly different.

In other words, you can't define a pure function, but you can *declare* a pure function.

### Further reading

If you are interested in this subject, I recommend *Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools* by Alfred V. Aho, Ravi Sethi and Jeffrey D. Ullman.

Comment: I guess pure methods `= 0` count to #5, but I'm not so sure about post qualified `const` methods as well

Comment: There are additional restrictions for `template` functions: they cannot be `virtual` members.

Comment: @Walter: I should clarify: the CFG is not a complete specification of what is possible, it just specifies the syntax.

Comment: @Serthy: There's actually a separate grammar for that, it's in section 9.2.

Comment: omg the dragon book :) kind of hoping it would be simpler than that but it never is right? Do you think that mapping each keyword/context keyword to its type (eg static -> decl specifier) could produce a tool that would give the ordering of things you feed it as input ? Or things are more context sensitive than that and it always takes finite state machines to get the picture?

Comment: Syntactic tools are usually designed to work with terms that are in the correct order already.  Honestly, writing a tool sounds like a lot more work here, I think you could fit all of the information you need on a notecard.